# Get JSON from input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, input

I am creating an interactive, sortable bootstrap form. The user will be able to add additional rows of input fields (and from dropdowns, but that's for later, I am taking it step by step) and the goal is to get data from them to JSON.

I managed to get the form creation part working (with help from a different stackoverflow thread), but I cannot get JSON to be created properly. What am I missing here?

Please see code below, I would greatly appreciate any comments.

```html
<div class="col">
  <button type="button" value="Add a field" class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Add row</button>
  <button type="button" value="Generate" class="btn btn-primary" id="preview">Generate JSON</button>
  <br><br><br>
  <div id="sortable">
    <!-- Filled by script -->
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<!-- Make form sortable using drag and drop -->
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable();
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
</script>
<!-- Create form and get JSON -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#preview").click(function() {
    var arr = {};
    arr.items = [];
    $(".fieldwrapper").each(function() {
      var entry = {}
      var neighborhood = $(this).find("input[name='neighborhood']").val();
      var url = $(this).find("input[name='url']").val();
      entry["url"] = url;
      entry["name"] = neighborhood;
      arr.items.push(entry);
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4));
  });
  $("#add").click(function() {
    var intId = $("#sortable div").length + 1;
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"form-row\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
    var name = $("<div class=\"form-group col-md-4\"><input name=\"neighborhood\" type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Name of Neighborhood\"class=\"form-control\"></div>");
    var url = $("<div class=\"form-group col-md-4\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"url\" placeholder=\"Paste here the URL of the Image\"class=\"form-control\"></div>");
    var removeButton = $("<div class=\"form-group col-md-4\"><button type=\"button\"class=\"btn btn-primary btn-sm\">Usuń</button></div>");
    removeButton.click(function() {
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    fieldWrapper.append(name);
    fieldWrapper.append(url);
    fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
    $("#sortable").append(fieldWrapper);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are looking to iterate over `.fieldwrapper` elements, but you don't seem to create any of those, you do use the class name `form-row` for the fieldWrapper element you create.

Comment: @MarkusMaga , much appreciated. You are absolutely right. That did the trick.